# Reader is not reading the data

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a function like this

```
try
    {


        using(var sConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        using(var sCommand = sConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            sCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT 
                                           TABLE_NAME
                                          AS
                                           TABLES
                                        FROM 
                                           INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
                                       WHERE 
                                           CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
                                         AND
                                           TABLE_NAME <> 'dtProperties'
                                    ORDER BY
                                           TABLE_NAME";
            sConnection.Open();
            using(var reader = sCommand.ExecuteReader()) // Troublesome line
            {                    
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(reader.GetString(0));
                }
            }
        }

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //All the exceptions are handled and written in the EventLog. 
        EventLog log = new EventLog("Application");
        log.Source = "MFDBAnalyser";
        log.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

On debugging, it is giving the result till the connection is open but the var Reader is not reading the data.

Can anybody point out where the error is!!

Comment: Do you mean it's executing without an exception, but giving no data? What does SQL Profiler show?

Comment: Can u give detail about exception u r geting

Comment: Can anybody tell me why it is happening.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have "var reader" rather than "SQLDataReader reader"?

Comment: Changing that also I have seen..its not working too for me!1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your provided code the same you run?

Strange behaviour of 'working' in debug, but not in runtime, usually happens if you have self initializing get properties. Something like this:

```
private string _name;

public string Name
{
  get {
    if (_name == null)
    {
      name = string.Empty;
    }
    return _name;
  }
  set {_name = value;}
}
```

So if you use _name directly and debugger displays such a property, it 'accidentally' initializes your property before use.

Answer (score 0):

Seen here in MSDN : [Reader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/9kcbe65k.aspx)

```
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));
    }
```

So maybe try with `reader[0]` instead of `reader.getString(0)` ?

**Edit** :

Try with this :

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        String ConnectionString = @"Data Source=SERVER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;User ID=USER;Password=PWD";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (SqlConnection sConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            String query = @"SELECT TABLE_NAME AS TABLES FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND TABLE_NAME <> 'dtProperties' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME";
            SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand(query, sConnection);
            sConnection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = comand.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("reader.hasRows == true !");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("reader.hasRows == FALSE !");
            }

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                sb.AppendLine(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

See if it works.

I created a new Winform application, tried it, it works for me.

Here was my output :

```
reader.hasRows == true !
Categorie
Chantier
...
And all my table names.
```

Comment: @Srivastava Ah, sorry ... Ok then, I fave a few questions (some may sound stupid) : 1. Is there an exception when your code runs ? 2. Does your query get lines when executed in a SQL Client ? 3. If you debug step by step, do you loop in the Reader.read() many times, meaning something is read ?

Comment: @Srivastava Ok then your answers are 1. No, 2. Yes and 3. No, it exits immediatly from the loop ?

Comment: @Srivastava Edited my post, try with this code, it's the one I use when I need it, instead of yours, see if it works and what the reader.Hasrows say.

Comment: @Srivastava Tell me if you encounter any problem with the piece of code I've written ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try placing **sConnection.Open()** before creating sCommand.