# Is the SqlDataReader.ExecuteReader skipped?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the same problem as here :
[Reader is not reading the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408385/reader-is-not-reading-the-data)
the reader is never executed.
I am trying to read from a local db. what could it be? the db is not empty but i never receive the `"hello from foo"`;
also it says that the reader doesn't have rows.

```
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;Integrated Security=True");


SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select * from employees;",myConn);

myConn.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();


while (reader.Read())
{
    MessageBox.Show(reader[0].ToString())
    MessageBox.Show("hello from foo");
}
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    MessageBox.Show("reader.hasRows == true !");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("reader.hasRows == FALSE !");
}

myConn.Close();
```

update:
i have changed the connection string to :" Data Source= my_server_name; Initial Catalog=employees; Integrated Security=True " now it works, thank you very much.

Comment: are you sure that the table is called employs and not employees?

Comment: If you don't get exceptions caused by malformed names then your database table 'employs' is empty. Or you are reading a different database than the one you are looking at.

Comment: try opening the connection before you give it `comm` and try putting your `while(reader.Read())` inside `if(reader.HasRows)`

Comment: If this code is in the Window's .Load event event and running on a 64 bit machine than any exceptions it's throwing will be hidden unless "Break when thrown" is turned on for CLR Exceptions.

Comment: i have tried all your advices but still the reader is not executed it is just skipped. i still get the message that it doesn't have rows  the db is not empty.

Comment: try removing `;` from your command. If still problem persists then definitely db is not properly configured. I see in your connectionstring you have not mentioned dbname. Even that might be the problem.

Comment: thank you Guruprasad Rao it says that the db is not recognized. but i can modify it using "show table data" from server explorer.